# how to retrieve timestamp that was lastly updated at with room database in android?

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I have been reading [Pagination3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#initialize) with RemoteMediator on official android developer document. I would like to know how to achieve `db.lastUpdated()` as it is described in the code snippet under `Define the initialize method`.
I tried it on room database instance and Dao but none of them works.